# How to show input box when checkbox is already checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have php for loop which its return 12 checkbox with input box.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <?php                                    
    $getChannel = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT ch_id, ch_name, ch_for FROM channel WHERE lg_id = '$lg_id' ");

    $ch_for     = array();
    $ch_name    = array();

    while ( $fetchChannel =  mysqli_fetch_array($getChannel) ) {
        $ch_id      = (int) $fetchChannel['ch_id'];
        $ch_for[]   = htmlspecialchars($fetchChannel['ch_for']);
        $ch_name[]  = htmlspecialchars($fetchChannel['ch_name']);
    }

    for ($x=1; $x<=12; $x++) {
        if(  in_array('ch'.$x, $ch_name)) {
            $sel = 'checked = "checked" ';
        } else {
            $sel = '';
        }
        ?>

        <div class="checkbox form-inline">
            <label><input <?php echo $sel; ?> type="checkbox" name="ch_name[]" value="ch<?php echo $x; ?>">CH<?php echo $x; ?></label>
            <input type="text" name="ch_for[]" value="" placeholder="Channel details" class="form-control ch_for">
        </div>                                    
        <?php
    }
    ?>                                    
</div>
```

If `$ch_name` is matched against the for loop `'ch'.$x` then I checked the checkbox.

Now I want to show corresponding input box using jQuery in which checkbox is checked already.

**jQuery Code :**

```
$('.ch_for').hide();

if ( $('.checkbox input:checkbox:checked').length > 0 ) {        
     $(this).closest('.checkbox').find('.ch_for').show();
}

$('.checkbox input:checkbox').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.checkbox').find('.ch_for').toggle('slow');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function:

```
// no-conflict safe document ready (shorthand version)
jQuery(function($) {
    // hide all of the inputs initially
    $('.ch_for').hide();

    // your original function to show / hide on click
    $('.checkbox input:checkbox').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('.checkbox').find('.ch_for').toggle('slow');
    }); 

    // put this in a function for reusability
    function showInputs() {
        // use .each to loop over every checked input
        $('.checkbox input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {        
            // inside .each, $(this) refers to the checkbox element
             $(this).closest('.checkbox').find('.ch_for').show();
        });
    }

    // call the function on initial load
    showInputs();
});
```

Comment: Let me try with this

Comment: Its showing `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` in console log

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I missed a closing `)` on the `.each`.  I've corrected that!